# Change gmail image in batch

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, drive

I have the following code which works for me individually, the idea is to be able to do the change in batches, and not one by one, how could I do this? I had thought of a spreadsheet to put the URL of the photo in Drive and call those urls, how could I do it?

```
function updateGmailPhotoFromDrive() {

  try {

    var userEmail = 'test@business.mail.com';
    var fileName  = userEmail + ".jpg";

    var blob = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next().getBlob();
    var data = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(blob.getBytes());

    AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.update({photoData: data}, userEmail);

  }

  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err.toString());
  }

}
```

Comment: Is your question how to retrieve a list of `userEmails` from a spreadsheet and update the corresponding user's photo via `AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.update`, without having to run the function manually each time?

Comment: @lamblichus I want in a spreadsheet to store the urls of the images in drive, for example a field in the spreadsheet called image and that field contains the example url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DMzLUsONrUZmYctdDPpLV79ufsDbYsAA2R2/view? usp = sharing23215

and call that URL from Apps Script to be applied as a profile picture for each user in the domain, but apply the change in a massive non-user-by-user way as I do in the attached code.

Comment: Do you mean updating the profile pictures in one HTTP request? If that's the case, you might want to use [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch). Mind you, this HTTP request will still be composed by many API calls, since there is no API method to update many user's photos at once, just the one you're using: [Users.photos: update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/photos/update)). Is that what you want to do?